# How to I add a button on top of iCarousel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, icarousel

I added the date label and the share button via code. Now I want to add a static button in the right top corner to open a slide out menu(I'm using MMDrawerController). If I'm adding the via code, it's moving with the carousel.

If I'm adding a button on the name label(My App) on the storyboard, it's not getting clicked and the carousel gesture is being registered instead of the button click.

How should I proceed to add a button for a slide out menu on the right ?

```
-(UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view{

UIView *magView = nil;

CGFloat height = self.myCarousel.bounds.size.height;
CGFloat width = self.myCarousel.bounds.size.width;

//Magazine View
magView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, width/1.35, height/1.75)];
magView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIImageView *magImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"4 1:2.jpg"]];
magImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width/1.35, height/1.75);
[magView addSubview:magImage];


//Date Label
UILabel *dateLabel = nil;
dateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, height/1.7, width/4, height/25)];
dateLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
dateLabel.text = @"12-03-2017";
dateLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Black" size:5];
dateLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

//Share Button
UIButton *shareButton = nil;
shareButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(width/1.49, height/1.7, height/25, height/25)];
shareButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[shareButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"share_icon_1x"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


[magView addSubview:dateLabel];
[magView addSubview:shareButton];

return magView;

}
```

**Simulator**

[image]

**Storyboard**

[image]

How do I proceed to add the button ?

Comment: Add button to storyboard and after adding carousel progamatically. add code to bring button to top on view. [self.view bringSubviewToFront:button].

Comment: @pawan I added the code to bring the button on top of the view, but no use. Even when I'm swiping on the label, the carousel is moving. Maybe that's why the button thing isn't working

Comment: actually, carousel is added on top of view .if you are adding it programatically then just after [self.view addSubview:carousel]; call [self.view bringSubviewToFront:button](make sure button is added on view befor calling it)

Comment: you can't inside the icarousel so you can add button which is subview of UIVIew

Answer (score 1):

Add button to storyboard and after adding carousel programmatically. add code to bring the button to top on view.

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:button];
```

if you are adding it programmatically then just after `[self.view addSubview:carousel];` 
call `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:button]`(make sure button is added on view before calling it)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. Instead of taking the view of the ViewController I dragged/dropped another view onto the ViewController and displayed the carousel on it. Now I can set the button easily. Thanks for the help though. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**It will help you**

```
[xyzButton.superview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

:)